# Add event handler to dynamically loaded component

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamically-generated, eventemitter

I have two components: `workflow` and `block`. The `block` components are loaded dynamically into `workflow` using a `directive` and the `ComponentFactory`.

The `block` component contains a button and I want to emit an event to the parent (`workflow`) when the button was clicked, therefore I added `@Output('onDelete') onDelete = new EventEmitter<boolean>()` in `BlockComponent` in order to be able to emit the event.

The problem which I encounter is adding the `event handler` on the `<app-block>`.
I tried to add it using `document.getElementsByTagName('app-block').addEventListener('(onDelete)', 'blockDeleted()')`  but it's not working.

**workflow.component.html**

```
<div clas="mainContent">
  <ng-template appWorkflowDirective></ng-template>
</div>
```

**workflow.component.ts**

```
private createNewBlockComponent(event, object): void {
   const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlockComponent);
   const componentRef = this.workflowsDirective.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

   (<BlockComponent>componentRef.instance).position = new BlockPosition(event.layerX, event.layerY) ;
}
```

I'm looking for the same behavior as in this [example](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) from angular

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't seem to go with your question.

Comment: @jbrown how come? `appWorkflowDirective` is the directive which I'm using in `.ts` in order to dynamically load the `block-components`

Comment: The `@Output` decorator allow you to bind to an event in the template. But you talk about dynamic component, so the `@Output` won't help you. Can you add the code containing the part with the ComponentFactory plz ?

Comment: @NoémiSalaün I added the code. That's what I want, to bind to an event sent by a dynamically loaded component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Generic example

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlockComponent);

const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

const blockInstance = componentRef.instance as BlockComponent;

blockInstance.onDelete.subscribe(() => {
    this.blockDeleted();
});
```

### Specific example for this question

```
private createNewBlockComponent(event, object): void {
   const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlockComponent);
   const componentRef = this.workflowsDirective.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

   (<BlockComponent>componentRef.instance).position = new BlockPosition(event.layerX, event.layerY) ;

   (<BlockComponent>componentRef.instance).onDelete.subscribe(() => {
      this.blockDeleted();
   }) ;
}
```